# Pull JSON data into a view SSMS

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column in SQL Server with JSON data in this format:

```
{"FormCode":"1224","Answers":[{"Type":"FirstName","Values":["Tony"]},{"Type":"LastName","Values":
["Tiger"]},{"Type":"IsExistingPatient","Values":["Maybe"]},{"Type":"Race","Values":["RaceValue1","RaceValue2"]}]}
```

I'm trying to pull that data into a view with each demographic in it's own column. For example:

| Table.ClientID | ExistingPatient | Race |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 987654321 | Maybe | RaceValue1, RaceValue2 |

My query is pulling the existing patient data into both the existing patient column and the race column. I can't figure out how to modify the query to pull the race values into the race column.

```
SELECT 
       Id,
       JSON_VALUE(anso.value, '$.Values[0]') AS ExistingPatient,
       JSON_VALUE(anso.value, '$.Values[0]') AS Race,
FROM Table
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JsonValue, '$.Answers') anso
WHERE Id in (
    SELECT TOP 5 Id
    FROM dbo.Table
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JsonValue, '$.Answers') ans
    WHERE JSON_VALUE(ans.value, '$.Type') = 'IsExistingPatient' 
    ORDER BY NEWID()
    )
    AND JSON_VALUE(anso.value, '$.Type') = 'IsExistingPatient'
```

I've tried adding
`AND JSON_VALUE(ans.value,'$.Type') = 'Race'` in the `where` conditions, but that returns no data whatsoever instead of 5 rows of data with existing patient data in the race field instead of race data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only looking for the first element of the Race values then you can use a an extra `cross apply` like this:

```sql
select
  Id,
  json_value(answer1.Value, '$.Values[0]') as ExistingPatient,
  json_value(answer2.Value, '$.Values[0]') as Race
from dbo.[Table]
cross apply openjson(JsonValue, '$.Answers') answer1
cross apply openjson(JsonValue, '$.Answers') answer2
where json_value(answer1.Value, '$.Type') = N'IsExistingPatient'
and json_value(answer2.Value, '$.Type') = N'Race'
```

Which yields:

| Id | ExistingPatient | Race |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Maybe | RaceValue1 |

But it seems like you're wanting to return a comma-delimited string of all the elements in Race values, so you'll also need to `string_agg` them like this:

```sql
select
  Id,
  json_value(answer1.Value, '$.Values[0]') as ExistingPatient,
  (
    select string_agg(raceValues.Value, N',')
    from openjson(answer2.Value, '$.Values') raceValues
  ) as Race
from dbo.[Table]
cross apply openjson(JsonValue, '$.Answers') answer1
cross apply openjson(JsonValue, '$.Answers') answer2
where json_value(answer1.Value, '$.Type') = N'IsExistingPatient'
and json_value(answer2.Value, '$.Type') = N'Race'
```

Which yields:

| Id | ExistingPatient | Race |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Maybe | RaceValue1,RaceValue2 |